# dplyr - group by and compute difference between rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is my example. I would like to group by col_1 and compute difference between row of col_2 per each group.

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- data.frame(col_1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), col_2= c(1,8, 6,7))
my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(diff = col_2 -lag(col_2)
```

Here is error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `diff` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: How many rows do you have for each group? If more than two, `my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% mutate(diff = col_2 -lag(col_2))` or `my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(diff = diff(col_2))` if always two.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Will there only be two numbers per group?

Comment: or: `my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(col_2)))`